# Django Middleware Login check

Tags: python, django, authentication, middleware, django-middleware

I want to restrict all pages for unauthenticated users. I wrote the following middleware:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def require_login(get_response):

    def middleware(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            response = get_response(request)
            return response

        return redirect('/login/')

    return middleware
```

The issue is that it also redirects to my Login page when it redirects to Login page (hope you got it). So it continuously redirects to my login page. What do I need to do about it? Is it okay to check if the requested page is Login page then don't check the if statement above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspect [`request.path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path) and if it equals your login URL then return the regular response

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def require_login(get_response):

    def middleware(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated or request.path == '/login/':
            response = get_response(request)
            return response

        return redirect('/login/')

    return middleware
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept your answer in 5 minutes. But the question, is it the best way to restrict all pages from unauthenticated users? Or maybe decorators would be better, or login_required from django.contrib.auth.decorators?

Comment: @MammadaliMammadaliyev I personally wouldn't implement a middleware like this, the LoginRequiredMixin can be added to class based views or a base class and it's then fairly explicit in the view. There will probably be more views that you will want to allow unauthenticated users to access and excluding them from this check may end up being cumbersome

Comment: Let's say I implement LoginRequiredMixin to all my cbv, then in my settings I set LOGIN_URL. Does it mean that I wouldn't then need to set something like **login_url = '/index/'** one by one in all my cbvs?

Comment: @MammadaliMammadaliyev exactly right, if you don't provide a `login_url` then it defaults to `settings.LOGIN_URL`